# Visual Studio Gallery reporting that template VSIX for Express SKU

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-gallery

I've written a Visual Studio extension, and am updating it in the Visual Studio Gallery. When uploading, it produces this error:

> You can only upload template VSIX files for the Visual Studio Express SKUs.

What's the source of the problem, and how can it be fixed?

[image]

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="dehungarian.Vsix..c7f6148f-43a7-4787-ab00-5f4b8a8352b9" Version="1.0.2" Language="en-US" Publisher="Phil Campbell"/>
    <DisplayName>dehungarian.Vsix</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">foo</Description>
    <MoreInfo>https://github.com/philoushka/dehungarian</MoreInfo>
    <License>EULA.txt</License>
    <Icon>icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>foo.png</PreviewImage>
    <Tags>foo</Tags>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="dehungarian" Path="|dehungarian|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Analyzer" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="dehungarian" Path="|dehungarian|"/>
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically responding to the error, I don't believe Express SKUs support Tool extension types, only Template and Control.  That's reinforced [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx), and it seems to be from the perspective of someone *installing* the extension.

However you're *uploading*, not installing, and so I believe it is an indirect result of the [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943167.aspx) trying to specify it is available for install with Express editions.

Can you check your vsix manifest for something like:

```
<SupportedProducts>
  <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>Express_All</Edition> <<<<<<<<< !!
  </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
```

If it's there, that would be what I'd try removing.

For [VS 2015 manifests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943167(v=vs.140).aspx), ensure these elements are removed, if they exist.

```
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress" />
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Turns out the manifest created by VS 2015 doesn't include the `SupportedProducts` element, but did have `InstallationTarget` elements with Express values.

Comment: Wasn't this restriction cleared with VS2015 (that Express SKU cannot be extended with tools)?